# The usage of ようだ with 何かを感じていた

Tags: grammar, particles

Could someone explain to me what it roughly means when a sentence is composed of "**somethingに**何かを感じていたようだ", such as "世界大戦に何かを感じていたようだ.

Answer (score 1):

感じる here is related to 感想 which roughly translates to "thoughts". So it roughly translates to `something seems to have invoked some thoughts in the person`.